# Removing full path from md5 output

Tags: output, sh, checksum, basename

By default the md5 command includes the full path in the output and doesn't seem to have an option to output the basename only. Although I can get around this using a script, I wondered if there is a simple way to output without the full path using a single command. It doesn't have to be md5 as my aim is just to verify there is no corruption in files stored on different machines in my own network. As I am doing a simple diff on list of files with different paths, I just need to avoid the path muddying the waters.

At the moment I am using

```
find -s directoryToBeChecked -type f -exec md5 {} \; > checksumsForComparison.txt
```

to create pairs of files and would like to manually check them using a graphical diff program like FileMerge.

I'm using MacOS 10.14 so the shell is sh 3.2

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about MacOS... But you could try if `find -s directoryToBeChecked -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename "$0") $(md5 -q "$0")"' {} \; > checksumsForComparison.txt` works for you.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for that. Your suggestion works and gives me exactly what I wanted. As you've just posted a comment rather than a reply I can't mark it as the solution.

Comment: There you go, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open a shell with a command argument echoing the `basename` and `md5` (with the `-q` flag thus only printing the hash).

```
find -s directoryToBeChecked -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename "$0") $(md5 -q "$0")"' {} \; > checksumsForComparison.txt
```